# Creating a loop for multiple dependent variables in logistic regression using a multiple imputation dataset?

Tags: r, loops, logistic-regression, imputation

**This previous question "How to repeatedly perform glm over multiple dependent variables after mice?" - did not work for me.** I don't understand how it incorporates the pooling of the mids.

######################

I need to repeat logistic regression for 7 dependent variables, using the same 5 predictor variables for each regression.

I need to do multiple imputation using mice before I perform the regressions.

I then need an output of exponentiated odds ratios and confidence intervals for each of the dependent variables.

Here is a smaller example:

```
 P1 <- c(7,8,5,NA)
 P2 <- c(10,12,11,12)
 P3 <- c(1,1,0,1)
 P4 <- c(1,1,1,0)

 R1 <- c(0,1,0,1)
 R2 <- c(0,0,1,0)
 R3 <- c(1,1,0,0)
 R4 <- c(0,1,1,1)
 R5 <- c(1,0,1,0)

df1 <- data.frame(P1,P2,P3,P4,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5)
cols <- c("P3","P4","R1","R2","R3","R4","R5")

 df1[cols] <- lapply(df1[cols], factor)
```

Multiple Imputation:

```
library(mice)
imp <- mice(df1, maxit=0)

predM <- imp$predictorMatrix

meth <- imp$method

imp2 <- mice(df1, maxit=5, 
         predictorMatrix = predM,
         method = meth, print = F)
```

Logistic Regression after pooling imputed data:

```
m1.mi <- with(imp2, glm(R1 ~ P1 + P2 + P3 + P4, family=binomial(link=logit)))

summary(pool(m1.mi),exponentiate=TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)
```

Is there a way to create a loop, that will produce an odds ratio and CIs for each dependent variable?

Any help appreciated, I apologise for my very limited knowledge in this area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reformulate` is neat for jobs like this. Define the process of one iteration in an anonymous function (those with `function(x)` or abbreviated `\(x)`) and put it into `lapply`. The `summary` can be subsetted to desired columns just like a data frame using the respective column `names` in brackets.

Let's use the `nhanes` data coming with `mice` in an example.

```
dvs <- c('age1', 'age2', 'age3')

res <- lapply(dvs, \(x) {
  mi <- with(imp, glm(reformulate(c('bmi', 'hyp', 'chl'), x), family=binomial))
  s <- summary(pool(mi), exponentiate=TRUE, conf.int=TRUE)
  `rownames<-`(s[c('estimate', '2.5 %', '97.5 %')], s$term) |> as.matrix()
}) |> setNames(dvs)
```

This gives a named list like this one,

```
res
# $age1
#                 estimate     2.5 %   97.5 %
# (Intercept) 2.197201e+04 0.0000000      Inf
# bmi         1.999346e+00 0.4691464 8.520549
# hyp         4.331347e-08 0.0000000      Inf
# chl         9.441578e-01 0.8403936 1.060734
# 
# $age2
#              estimate        2.5 %      97.5 %
# (Intercept) 0.9300514 0.0002224722 3888.105740
# bmi         0.8891490 0.6550513927    1.206907
# hyp         2.8818840 0.2054892623   40.416981
# chl         1.0046189 0.9757483655    1.034344
# 
# $age3
#              estimate        2.5 %       97.5 %
# (Intercept) 3.5383401 1.087542e-07 1.151206e+08
# bmi         0.6442681 2.792523e-01 1.486403e+00
# hyp         5.9651279 5.954159e-02 5.976117e+02
# chl         1.0323994 9.885890e-01 1.078151e+00
```

where you can output individual elements in this way:

```
res$age1
#                 estimate     2.5 %   97.5 %
# (Intercept) 2.197201e+04 0.0000000      Inf
# bmi         1.999346e+00 0.4691464 8.520549
# hyp         4.331347e-08 0.0000000      Inf
# chl         9.441578e-01 0.8403936 1.060734
```

Where

```
class(res$age1)
# [1] "matrix" "array"
```

If you want class `"data.frame"` in the list elements, just leave out the `|> as.matrix()` part.

---

*Data:*

```
data("nhanes", package='mice')
nhanes <- transform(nhanes, age1=age == 1, age2=age == 2, age3=age == 3)
library(mice)
imp0 <- mice(nhanes, maxit=0)
imp <- mice(nhanes, maxit=5, 
            predictorMatrix=imp0$predictorMatrix,
            method=imp0$method, print=F)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
model_list <- lapply( paste0("R",1:5),function(dep_var){
  formula <- as.formula(paste0(dep_var,"~ P1 + P2 + P3 + P4"))
  m1.mi <- with(imp2, glm(formula, family=binomial(link=logit)))
  
  summary(pool(m1.mi),exponentiate=TRUE, conf.int = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(depvar = dep_var)
})

do.call(rbind,model_list)

          term      estimate std.error     statistic df   p.value 2.5 % 97.5 % depvar
1  (Intercept) 1.704353e-121 621431.55 -4.474823e-04  0 0.9999859   NaN    NaN     R1
2           P1  1.241210e+04  38928.27  2.421486e-04  0 0.9999923   NaN    NaN     R1
3           P2  1.540603e+08  59463.92  3.170469e-04  0 0.9999900   NaN    NaN     R1
4           P3            NA        NA            NA NA        NA    NA     NA     R1
5           P4            NA        NA            NA NA        NA    NA     NA     R1
6  (Intercept)  1.382828e+06 621431.49  2.275334e-05  0 0.9999993   NaN    NaN     R2
7           P1  6.490963e-09  38928.28 -4.842972e-04  0 0.9999847   NaN    NaN     R2
8           P2  1.241211e+04  59463.92  1.585235e-04  0 0.9999950   NaN    NaN     R2
9           P3            NA        NA            NA NA        NA    NA     NA     R2
10          P4            NA        NA            NA NA        NA    NA     NA     R2
11 (Intercept)  7.231535e-07 621431.51 -2.275334e-05  0 0.9999993   NaN    NaN     R3
12          P1  1.540603e+08  38928.27  4.842972e-04  0 0.9999847   NaN    NaN     R3
13          P2  8.056654e-05  59463.92 -1.585235e-04  0 0.9999950   NaN    NaN     R3
14          P3            NA        NA            NA NA        NA    NA     NA     R3
15          P4            NA        NA            NA NA        NA    NA     NA     R3
16 (Intercept) 4.045223e-105 621431.46 -3.868068e-04  0 0.9999878   NaN    NaN     R4
17          P1  8.056652e-05  38928.27 -2.421486e-04  0 0.9999923   NaN    NaN     R4
18          P2  1.912213e+12  59463.92  4.755705e-04  0 0.9999850   NaN    NaN     R4
19          P3            NA        NA            NA NA        NA    NA     NA     R4
20          P4            NA        NA            NA NA        NA    NA     NA     R4
21 (Intercept) 5.867312e+120 621431.46  4.474823e-04  0 0.9999859   NaN    NaN     R5
22          P1  8.056650e-05  38928.28 -2.421486e-04  0 0.9999923   NaN    NaN     R5
23          P2  6.490965e-09  59463.92 -3.170470e-04  0 0.9999900   NaN    NaN     R5
24          P3            NA        NA            NA NA        NA    NA     NA     R5
25          P4            NA        NA            NA NA        NA    NA     NA     R5
```

Which produces a long format of all your analysis. The trick is only creating your regression formula with the `as.formula` function. I use `lapply` so it produces a list, which is easier to handle. the `do.call` just bind the results together (and that is why I add what is the dependent variable in your summary)